# Delete Cookie using JavaScript , in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, cookies

The same code does delete cookies from the page when the page is opened directly but not when embedded as an iframe.

```
document.cookie="uuid=null ; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/"
```

Comment: Is the domain of iframe url and domain of page with iframe is same or different?

Comment: They are from different domain

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by sending ajax request to a page that removes cookies via http header.